# How can I access to Dynamics CRM via java

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dynamics-crm

I'm new with MS Dynamics CRM 2016 and I'm searching for the best solution to invoke Dynamics methods and web services via java Application.

is Dynamics exposes any REST or SOAP web services via deployment URL?
is there any maven or gradle dependency that can I use to invoke CRM methods?

For example, for Dynamics 2011 I found Java MSCRM API but I don't know if I can use it with Dynamic 2016.

Also, Dynamic 2016 expose an SDK only for JavaScript, c#, VB. How can I use that with Java?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about asking Google?
First hit: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/jasonlattimersblog/archive/2015/11/24/crm-web-api-using-java

Comment: This link shows how can we identify Active Directory user to invoke Dynamics WS. But by looking at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334767.aspx I can understand how invoking WS. Thank you

Comment: Actually that link I provided starts with that, but also describes how to access and links a repo on GitHub where this is actually done. :-)